# include an aliased field in mysql to another alias

Tags: mysql, sql, alias

i have a table that stores values in hour-minute float format and im pulling the data from the database while converting hour-minute float to minutes using this query.

```
SELECT 
    DailyTimelog.id,
    DailyTimelog.payroll_cut_off_id,
    DailyTimelog.employee_id,
    DailyTimelog.work_shift_id,
    DailyTimelog.employee_status,
    DailyTimelog.timelog_date,
    DailyTimelog.is_rest_day,
    DailyTimelog.is_on_leave,
    DailyTimelog.is_holiday,
    DailyTimelog.is_regular_holiday,
    DailyTimelog.is_special_holiday,
    DailyTimelog.is_absent,
    (
        (SUBSTRING_INDEX(tardiness_hours, '.', 1)*60)
        +(
            case when (INSTR(tardiness_hours, '.') = 0) 
                THEN 0 
                ELSE SUBSTRING_INDEX(tardiness_hours, '.', -1) 
            END)
    ) as tardiness_hours,
    (
        (SUBSTRING_INDEX(leave_hours, '.', 1)*60)
        +(
            case when (INSTR(leave_hours, '.') = 0) 
                THEN 0 
                ELSE SUBSTRING_INDEX(leave_hours, '.', -1) 
            END)
    ) as leave_hours,
    DailyTimelog.leave_credit_used,
    (
        (SUBSTRING_INDEX(normal_work_hrs, '.', 1)*60)
        +(
            case when (INSTR(normal_work_hrs, '.') = 0) 
                THEN 0 
                ELSE SUBSTRING_INDEX(normal_work_hrs, '.', -1) 
            END)
    ) as normal_work_hrs,
    (
        (SUBSTRING_INDEX(overtime_work_hrs, '.', 1)*60)
        +(
            case when (INSTR(overtime_work_hrs, '.') = 0) 
                THEN 0 
                ELSE SUBSTRING_INDEX(overtime_work_hrs, '.', -1) 
            END)
    ) as overtime_work_hrs,
    (
        (SUBSTRING_INDEX(night_premium_work_hrs, '.', 1)*60)
        +(
            case when (INSTR(night_premium_work_hrs, '.') = 0) 
                THEN 0 
                ELSE SUBSTRING_INDEX(night_premium_work_hrs, '.', -1) 
            END)
    ) as night_premium_work_hrs

    FROM `daily_timelogs` as DailyTimelog WHERE DailyTimelog.payroll_cut_off_id = 404
```

when i output the data using print_f() i get something like this:

```
 [DailyTimelog] => Array
            (
                [id] => 93608
                [payroll_cut_off_id] => 404
                [employee_id] => 126
                [work_shift_id] => 11
                [employee_status] => 2
                [timelog_date] => 2016-03-27
                [is_rest_day] => 1
                [is_on_leave] => 
                [is_holiday] => 
                [is_regular_holiday] => 
                [is_special_holiday] => 
                [is_absent] => 
                [leave_credit_used] => 0
            )

        [0] => Array
            (
                [tardiness_hours] => 0
                [leave_hours] => 0
                [normal_work_hrs] => 0
                [overtime_work_hrs] => 0
                [night_premium_work_hrs] => 0
            )
```

is there a way to include index 0 to the DailyTimelogs index while still on mysql?